# Multi Label Semantic Segmentation - One class is way behind

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to build a Multi-Label Semantic Segmentation model, but while training, when I'm looking at the validation set, I can see that one label is far far behind, and in the end, he is not getting good results.

I'm using a U-net model with resnet50 backbone, tried categorial-cross-entropy loss, dice-loss, jaccard loss, but couldn't find a way to leverage this class.

I tried to give this class more weight in the loss function, I even tried to give this class over 90% and still the states were low.

Someone have any Idea, method, a way of action, even tricks from his experience to help me with that issue? is it a common problem? or I need to check my basics?

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple classes in segmentation, one must pay attention to the classes' representation in the data-set. The first thing to do would be to check the confusion matrix and see if the class that's falling behind gets confused with another class. If it is confused with a particular class then the issue is probably coming for the data set. However, if the class representation seem correct, you should check out the model itself.

I've worked with a similar U-net model for the same purpose and have used a manually weighted L2-loss and it seemed to do the trick. Maybe you can try that.

Another thing you can try out is to load encoder weights (for resnet50) pre-trained on ImageNet (They can be found online), this will ease your model recognition of the said class.

Hope this can help !